# Error Code 0x0000005D while installing Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, installation

My friend was installing Windows 8 to our network lab's computers. During the installation, this error message appeared:

> Your PC needs to restart
>   Please hold down the power button
>   Error Code 0x0000005D
>   Parameters
>   0x030F0401
>   0x756E6547
>   0x49656E69
>   0x6C65746E

What should he do to solve this problem?

[image: Settings 1][image: Settings 2][image: Settings 3][image: VB Stuck at this][image: Error]

Comment: Is the processor of the computer Pentium 4?

Comment: Are you upgrading or installing new ?

Comment: yeah im installing the new win8

Comment: @Hunter what do you want to know? It is already answered with a lot of details.

Comment: @magicandre1981 My PC is Intel i5 2nd gen processor,Intel DH67BL motherboard and updated bios.Still I am unable to install windows 8 on Virtualbox while I can install W8 normally on PC.The execution disable bit didn't help me in anyway en/dis it had no effect on the installation.Also I had successfully installed W8 on VBox previously many times.But unable to install it now.I tried everything present in the Bios in no vain.So what can I do to install it as I need install.wim from Windows 8.1 (in the installation disc install.esd is present and to get it I need to install W8 on virtualbox)

Comment: @Hunter You need to activate NX Bit/PAE inside the VM option ("Enable PAE/NX").

Comment: @magicandre1981 windows 8 would throw another error if it wasn't enabled already. It's enabled but still cannot install.

Comment: @Hunter is the "Virtualization Technology (VT)" feature enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: @magicandre1981 It is as I can install other OSes fine. It's only windows 8/8.1

Comment: Try this : `"c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" setextradata [vmname] VBoxInternal/CPUM/CMPXCHG16B 1` ([source](http://4sysops.com/forums/topic/windows-server-2012-r2-on-virtual-box-error-0x000000c4/)). Ensure also the VM has at least 2 cores.

Comment: @hunter this is correct. Win8 is the first Windows which requires PAE. In a VM it needs VT-x to use PAE.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I think that when I select windows 8 it selects it's essential features itself. All these options you tell me are already enabled in the machine as I too know what features windows 8 needs to operate on. But I still don't manage to install it on VB.

Comment: @harrymc It managed to do nothing. After all tries the windows is always stuck at the Blue window, always that same error. I don't know what to do. I have installed windows 8 many times but don't know what has happened.

Comment: @hunter  post pictures of your VirtualBox VM settings

Comment: @harrymc Actually I have tried older and older versions with the latest version too. But it doesn't install. Also I don't want to install VMware as VB is too easy to use.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have posted the images just as you asked. Please help me to install windows 8.1 on my PC.

Comment: What's left is to try VMware Workstation trial to create the VM. VirtualBox can directly use the VMware vmdk virtual disk in a new VM.

Comment: try to assign 2 CPU cores. Also upload the **vbox.log**

Comment: @magicandre1981: I also suggested 2 cores and I still wonder if this was tried or not. Viewing vbox.log is an excellent suggestion.

Comment: Just to mention: I run a copy of Win 8.1 in VBox, and it's running on 1 (virtual) CPU.

Answer (score 7):

This message means the CPU doesn't support the required CPU features like SSE2, PAE and NX-Bit.

Check this for more details:

**[PAE/NX/SSE2 Support Requirement Guide for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh975398.aspx)**

Comment: all of computers have save hardwares  but two of them had that error

Comment: make sure NX Bit is enabled in the BIOS. read the .Doc file it explains everything "Attempting to boot a system without NX or SSE2 support will result in bugcheck. Users will get the UNSUPPORTED_PROCESSOR code (0x0000005D) "

Comment: i checked the .doc and all of my computers but they have same hardwares in all slots but just 1 of those computers cannot be instaleld... is it maybe for out of dated BIOS?

Comment: again, go into the BIOS and make sure NX Bit is enabled. it is sometimes labeled as "eXecute Disabled (XD)" and not NX.

Comment: yes! your right and i was looking for NX tonight a lot but i couln't find it and there is execute disabled...thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In those two machines, someone probably disabled NX. Go into the BIOS settings and see if you can enable it and retry the installation. It may be called something like "processor security", "execution prevention", "DEP" or similar. Windows 8 will not install on a machine without this enabled: http://www.jermsmit.com/?p=1829

Comment: I am unable to find any No-Execution option in my BIOS. I could install windows 8 on Vbox previously (have installed many times) but now it is showing me this error after loading bios defaults. I don't know what settings did I do previously but windows 8 on Vbox worked perfectly. I can't find the settings in my BIOS can somebody point me out where it could be. My board is Intel DH67BL.

Comment: I can fully install windows 8 on my PC, but not on Vbox.

Comment: Execution disable bit was enabled in my BIOS so I disabled it but it didn't work at all. Execution disable bit (enabled or disabled) had no effect on it. Also DEP is turned on for VB and I cannot disable it for VB.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are helpful. However, there are some important details regarding Error Code 0x0000005D that seem to be not well-documented.

- Most documentation indicates that this error is associated with installing Windows 8. However, this error seems to occur because of new requirements in Win8 PE. It could occur if you were installing Windows 7 from a build that was created using MDT 2012. *I realize that you can hack the MDT 2012 script to use Win7 PE instead of Win8 PE but this isn't recommended.* I have also read threads pertaining to this error and SCCM.
- Some Pentium 4s and other really old hardware (about the time XP SP2 was released) predate this particular security feature and therefore no BIOS settings can be modified in order to make Win8 setup work. For this older hardware, you should continue install Windows 7 using a build created with MDT 2010.

The following document contains additional relevant details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh975398.aspx?ppud=4

Answer (score 0):

For those using VirtualBox you need to manually run the following command:

```
"c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" setextradata "VM Name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/CMPXCHG16B 1
```

Source: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=56196